# Webdriver: Send keys to canvas using JS

Tags: javascript, selenium, canvas, webdriver

I have this canvas game which listens for key presses. Now I'm trying to use Selenium Webdriver to automate gameplay. However, when I try to send a key press to the canvas I get the following error:

```
Error: Not a modifier key
```

Here is the code:

```
browser.findElement(webdriver.By.css('#canvas')).then(function(result){
    var as = new webdriver.ActionSequence(browser);                                          
    as.keyUp(webdriver.Key.SPACE);
});
```

Any help would be appreciated ?

Answer (score 1):

Try with regular `sendKeys()`:

```
as.sendKeys(webdriver.Key.SPACE);
```

Or, with `keyDown()` and then `keyUp()`:

```
as.keyDown(webdriver.Key.SPACE).keyUp(webdriver.Key.SPACE);
```